# How remove user from multiple groups at once Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to remove the user from multiple groups at once when changing from an 'individual' to 'company' on write method of a contact form.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    user = self.env['res.users'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.id)])
    if 'company_type' in values:
        if values["company_type"] == "company":
            # want to add in below group
            """[(6, 0, [self.env.ref('base.group_user').id,
                                           self.env.ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads').id,
                                           self.env.ref('survey.group_survey_manager').id
                                           ])]"""

            # want to remove from below group
            """[(6, 0, [self.env.ref('base.group_portal').id,
                                           self.env.ref('survey.group_survey_user').id,
                                           ])]"""
    res = super(Contact, self).write(values)
    return res
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you want to remove some groups and add some other groups, first when you use `api.multi` always expect that the self contains more than one record, so when you do this `self.id` you will probably have the famous `singleton Error`.

second don't start searching for users only if you are going to do something with them, so move the search inside the `if statement`.

```py
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    if values.get('company_type', False) ==  "company":
        users = self.env['res.users'].search([('partner_id', 'in', self.ids)])
        # remove some groups: [(3, id_of_group), ....etc]
        to_remove = [(3, self.env.ref(group_xml_id).id) for group_xml_id in ['base.group_portal', 'survey.group_survey_user']]
        # add some groups [(4, id_of_group), ... ect]
        to_add =  [(4, self.env.ref(group_xml_id).id) for group_xml_id in ['base.group_user', 
                                                                           'sales_team.group_sale_salesman_all_leads',
                                                                           'survey.group_survey_manager']]
        # contatenate the list to call write only one time
        users.write({'groups_id': to_remove + to_add})

    return super(Contact, self).write(values)
```

When you want to **remove** record from many2many field use `command` `(3, id_of_record)`, and when you want to **add** a record `(4, id_of_record)`:

Odoo ORM API documentation:

> One2many and Many2many use a special “commands” format to manipulate
>   the set of records stored in/associated with the field.
>
> This format is a list of triplets executed sequentially, where each
>   triplet is a command to execute on the set of records. Not all
>   commands apply in all situations. Possible commands are:

`(0, _, values):` adds a new record created from the provided value dict.

`(1, id, values):` updates an existing record of id id with the values in values. Can not be used in create().

`(2, id, _):`  removes the record of id id from the set, then deletes it (from the database). Can 
not be used in create().

`(3, id, _):`  removes the record of id id from the set, but does not delete it. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().

`(4, id, _) :`  adds an existing record of id id to the set. Can not be used on One2many.

`(5, _, _):`  removes all records from the set, equivalent to using the command 3 on every record explicitly. Can not be used on One2many. Can not be used in create().

`(6, _, ids):`  replaces all existing records in the set by the ids list, equivalent to using the command 5 followed by a command 4 for each id in ids.